# I've been travelling/I've travelled for 4 hours

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

It is now 1 p.m and I've been travelling for 4 hours and have just arrived. The journey was quite exhausting so I say: "I'm tired because I've just been travelling for 4 hours.

At 4 p.m I'm still tired of the journey, but a couple of hours have passed. Can I still say: " I'm tired because I've been travelling for 4 hours, or would it be better to use present perfect simple: "I'm tired because I have travelled for 4 hours ( today).

Comment: It's a stylistic choice / judgement call. There's nothing inherently "incorrect" about choosing to use the continuous form or not, in *either* context (immediately upon arrival, or a couple of hours later). But I personally would normally only say *I've been travelling for several hours* for a very short period after arrival. Later that evening when I say I'm going to bed early, I might explain myself by saying *I'm tired because **I was travelling** for several hours this afternoon*. But there are no rights and wrongs here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "a very short period after arrival". How short is short?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? :) One day I might think that less than 10 minutes is "short", but another day I might think anything up to several hours can count as "short". It's the *principle* that matters here, not the exact cutoff point between two different verb forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, but what do you mean by principle?

Comment: The principle that the shorter the time between the earlier ***doing** something* and the later ***talking** about it*, the more appropriate it is to use a continuous verb form. But there's no specific amount of time where you can say "If it's less than this, use one version; if it's more, use the other version". Both versions are at least "acceptable" regardless of elapsed time between action and speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I'm tired because I travelled for several hours this afternoon". Is this idiomatic?

Comment: Not really, no. If it's *still* afternoon, *...because I **have been travelling** for several hours.* If not, *...because I **was travelling** for several hours*. But it depends on the *specific* verb - it would perfectly idiomatic to say *I'm wide awake because I **slept** for several hours this afternoon*. (And before you ask - I *don't* know how to explain why Simple Past "slept" works in such constructions, but "travelled" *doesn't!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If it still afternoon, can I say: "I'm tired because I've been travelling for four hours this afternoon"?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly say that. But in practice I doubt many people would include "this afternoon", because Present Perfect already implies "very recently" (i.e. - you could really only say it in the late afternoon / early evening of the travel day, so it's contextually obvious *when* you did the four hours travel anyway).